# Can I use a D.O. Industries Navitron 50mm f0.95 lens on a Nikon Camera?

Tags: lens, nikon, lens-mount, lens-adapter, adapter

I have a D.O. Industries Navitron 50mm f0.95 and would like to use it on a nikon camera. Is there a mount that can adapt this lens to nikon cameras?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No. There are several problems here. This lens looks a lot like the Senko 50mm f/0.95, i.e., it is a C-mount lens *for 1" format video.*  This lens vignettes even on micro four-thirds (2x crop). There's no way the image circle will cover an APS-C or full-frame camera, and the registration distance is much much smaller than that of Nikon F.  In order to get the lens close enough to the sensor to focus properly, you'd have to remove your camera's mirrorbox.

See also:

[Can I use lens brand X on interchangeable lens camera brand Y?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/62000/can-i-use-lens-brand-x-on-interchangeable-lens-camera-brand-y)

Answer (score 4):

No, because the register (distance from the mounting flange of the lens to the sensor plane) is quite short.